# Name of a space with both a topology and a metric that are not compatible?

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, terminology

Let $(X,\tau,d)$ be a space where $\tau$ is a topology and $d$ is a metric, where the topology $\tau$ is not necessarily compatible with $d$.

Is there a canonical name for such a structure (maybe under some extra assumption on the relation between the metric and the topology)?

For example, assuming that all closed balls $\overline{B}(x,\epsilon)=\{y\in X\mid d(x,y)\leq \epsilon\}$ define with the metric are also closed in the topology $(X,\tau)$.

**Edit:**  I will give some more context accordingly to the comments, since the question as stated right now might be a bit too general.

Spaces with two topologies $(X,\tau,\sigma)$ are called bitopological spaces, and there is a lot of theory behind them.
I recall from a conversation that if the second topology $\sigma$ comes from a metric $d$ and the metric interacts "nicely" with the topology, this structure $(X,\tau,d)$ goes under a different name and that this notion has a wide literature as well.

I was hoping to get some information about this type of structure.

Comment: The reason for the downvotes is that most metric spaces also have a different topology (or many) that is not metrizable. For example, think about the indiscrete topology.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that this occurs a lot in a nontrivial way in Condensed Mathematics.  E.g. we have $A_r=\{f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[\![x]\!]:\|f\|_r<\infty\}$, where $\|\sum_na_nx^n\|_r=\sum_n|a_n|r^n$, and this has a pro-discrete $x$-adic topology as well as a metric topology derived from $\|\cdot\|_r$, and both are important.

Comment: Ok, but why this would make the question silly? 
Every group $(G, +, 0)$ has many other operations $\cdot$ and many of them are not group operations. And yet groups that have one more distributive operation $\cdot$ have a name (rings) and a wonderful theory behind them and are far from silly.
In the same way, spaces with two topologies that interact have a name and the theory behind them (bitopological spaces). I recall from a discussion that there is a name and a lot of literature also about spaces with a topology and a metric that interact. I was hoping to find a reference to this.

Comment: But thank you for the comments, I will change the question to explain better the goal.

Comment: Try to search for "topometric spaces", i.e. spaces of the form $(X,\tau, \rho)$ where $\tau$ is a topology and $\rho$ is a metric which is lower semi-continuous with respect to the topology. These are useful in continuous logic.

Comment: @BenjaminVejnar thank you that's a good answer and a good starting point for finding references. If you want to post it as an answer I'll close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "topometric space" is a triple $(X,\tau,\rho)$ where $\tau$ is a topology on $X$ and $\rho$ is a metric on $X$ which is lower semi-continuous with respect to the topology. These are useful in continuous logic. More details can be found in papers by Ben Yaacov.